# Countif on dynamic rows in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

Hey I have a question for MS Access.

In Excel I would use the function =countif(A1:$A$2000; $B$3). So it only counts the ones in the same row and below.

How do I do that in MS Access? Something like count(iff([]))?

Cheers

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A1:$A$2000)` is not valid syntax - the *criteria* parameter is missing.

Comment: yes right, thanks. that was just a quick example for excel. Ill change it in my post. The question is how to do this function in access/sql

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an [IIF function in ms-access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3). You can get the count if with a pipeline like:

```
SELECT Sum(IIf(id / 2 = id \ 2, 1, 0)) AS sum_of_even
FROM table;
```

In this case you obtain the sum of even ids. You can change the condition `id / 2 = id \ 2` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

try this

counttotal: Count(IIf([credit]<20000,[credit],Null))

where credit is name of column, and you want to count the number of records where the value in the credit column is less than  to 20,000

Comment: Thank you, but this does not seem to work. An example: In row 100, it should countif from row 100 to 20,000. In row 15942, it should do countif from row 15,942 to 20,000.

Comment: Ok. This is a modified function  =Count(IIf([credit]>=[credit]<=20000,[credit],Null))     where credit is name of auto number field, pls note that   the field must be an autonumber, e.g pkey.